# Can't fit plane to nurbs path to create a race track

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, path, nurbs-surface

I'm new here and I'm making a racing track for [Assetto Corsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assetto_Corsa).
I don't know what's exactly happening, but something doesn't let me to apply a *Curve modifier* to a plane.
I'll explain myself: to make the track, first I added a *Nurbs Path* (*Add > Curve > Path*) and closed it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.
Here's the problem: I add a plane (to make the road), then I add a modifier of array to it to make it long as the path is, this modifier works ok, but when I add the next modifier (curve) and select the nurbs path on the object selector the plane disappears and I don't know why. Please someone help me, it's very important for me.
I leave a screenshot as well as the .blend file. If you need something else just comment; I'll be watching this question and replying very fast.

Thanks in advance! Hope someone can help me.

[image: Up: Before adding the curve modifier. Down: After adding it.]

.blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make the *curve* and *plane* have the same origin point. Apply transformations (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Rotation & Scale*) in *Object Mode* to both objects. Subdivide the *plane* with *loopcuts* in *Edit Mode* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). Give the *plane* the ***Curve Modifier*** and set the *Path* as a target. Choose the right *deformation axis*. Then go to the *Curve* header and check the ***Stretch*** and ***Bound Clamps*** checkboxes in a Shape panel.
[image]

To make te plane more detailed along a *curve* subdivide the *plane* with <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Subdivise* or add more edgeloops at the start. 
[image]

---

***EDIT:*** Deleted unnecessary points of your *curve path* and it works fine. Remember to use *apply modifier while in edit mode* option. It's very helpful in this case.
[image]

Here's the .blend: [image]

Comment: I've done exactly the same as sou Say, Paul and that's what I get:

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/vszyk12tv/

Comment: Thanks for you fast reply. Hope you can help me fast as possible :)

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the path

Comment: I've checked your .blend and you're right- your curve has additional, unnecessary points. I'll try to delete them and see if it works.

Comment: thanks! works so good but I have a pair of questions:
1. How can I make the road wider? it measures 4 meters and I want it to measure 8m
2. How can I see the yellow lines on the track on edit mode? I don't know how to edit anything from the .blend you gave me.
Thank you

Comment: I've added a new (more user friendly :)) .blend  to my answer. 1.just scale it along the x axis in *Object Mode* (if you scale too much the mesh may overlap, so you'll have to clean it up after applying a *curve modifier* to it) 2. Use buttons shown in the red frame (last picture in my answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply man. I am currently having no time so I will comment when I have time to take a look to the last .blend. Anyways thank you so much, you're helping me a lot.

Comment: Been triying for a while and I fitted the road to the size I like but now another problem became. I can't add any texture to the rop

Comment: pressed enter by accident... I was saying that I can't add any texture to the road. I'm triying to add a texture called road.png. So I add the material to the plane, then I add a "Image or movie" texture and select it from the file browser and in the mapping section of the propierties I celect Coordinates: UV. I change the viewport shading to textures and it does nothing, It stills with the same default black texture. What am I doing wrong? I left you the link to the .blend file, thank you, teacher! ;) [link](https://mega.nz/#!kh9DFLpC!24LbIJx26qXq9CpABszjz-rltgEXPCf5XGTVGUZARlQ) @PaulGonet

Comment: I fouund what was going off, my light was too low so i was seeing the track in black on the viewport and the render.

Comment: Nil, sorry I didn't answer your comments. I wasn't at home for a few days. Hope everything works fine for you now. Or maybe there's something else I can help you with :)?

Answer (score -1):

just saw your comment. I'm answering because this morning I created an accound and just deleted the other account cause it was a temporary account and now I can't comment because I have less than 50 points of reputation... nevermind. 
thanks for commenting again and don't worry, we all have things to do haha
I'm currently having some issues with the walls on the track.
I posted a question before, take a look and better comment there so we can keep threads clean. I'll wait for your comment, thank you man and welcome back! :)
Oh man, just saw a lot of people answered and I asked for it only 2 hours ago... this website is great, there is a lot of people who is ready to help you on avery case. take a look and thanks a lot, you helped me so much.
[walls on the track](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66013/how-can-i-make-a-wall-around-a-road-on-a-cars-track)