# How can I make a wall around a road on a cars track?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I'm new on blender and I'm doing (at least trying) a Assetto Corsa track.
The question is about creating a wall on the two sides of the road. 
I created a wall with a cube, added an array modifier pointing to my nurbs path and then I created a curve modifier, so the wall follows the middle of the road. But I can't edit the X axis of that wall, so I can't scale it to match the outside or the inside of the road. It looks like this:
[image: track]
Any suggestions?

Here I leave you my .blend so you can check anything you need.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Hello @metaphor_set. How about to python scripts? how can I share them? Thanks

Comment: @MCunha - Python scripts are plain ASCII text files. No need to store them outside of BlenderSE. If you want to post them here, you can use the "code sample" feature of the editor.

Answer (score 3):

Enter wall edit mode and move it along local Z axis, then duplicate it and move it again on the Z axis. To know better what you're doing, turn Display modifier in edit mode and adjust edit cage to modifier in modifiers stack.Like this:
[image]

Comment: Well done! I didn't remember to do that on my answer! Very cool!

Comment: Thanx mate, glad you like it :)

Comment: thank you all for answering! I've placed the walls as them should but I don't know how to select the faces of any of the walls individually

Comment: I mean, when I right click one of the walls, all the array selects

Comment: oh, one more thing, when I try to edit the texture on the UV/Image editor I can't see the wall on it (by doing a reset and then a follow active quads). IDK if it is related to selecting individually the faces or what...

Comment: You can't select single faces individually, cause they are still one object duplicated multiple times and options, that you enabled on modifiers, only helps to visualise in edit mode, how the mesh looks like after using this modifiers. To be able to select individual faces, you would have to apply modifiers to the mesh.

Answer (score 1):

it's quite easy with your data: go to edit mode (press TAB), make your selections as edges (press CTRL+TAB >Edges), select the edge loop you want (ALT+rightclick), extrude in Zaxys (press E > press Z > type 0.01. Repeat the process for the other side of the road. You should get something like the image below[image: road_wall]. Optionally, if you want these walls to be a separate object, select the higher edges (shift+alt+rightclick), press CTRL+TAB for face mode, press CTRL+plus until desired faces are selected, press P, and separate by selection.

Comment: PS.: I say it's easy with your data, because the model itself was well constructed in order to do that. However, you have areas that the same space is ocuppied by more than one face (tight curve road areas). You have to edit it, in order to don't get strange artifacts (while rendering or other operation), and so the wall don't go into the road it self.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that your curve object is what makes it hard to model the road details. Here is how to clean it up a bit.

First, I deleted the Plane and the Cube, both of them had rotated axes, were way too small and can be recreated quickly later.

For a flat street, it's the easiest way to use a flat curve. (The "not twisted" kind of flat.)
This is not the case in your `.blend` file.

[image: Tilted Curve Segments]

---

To flatten the curve, select all control points in Edit Mode.
Then use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to reset the tilt, or find it in the menu in `Curve > Control Points > Clear Tilt`.

[image: Clear Tilt Menu]

---

The curve should now look like this, which already resembles a road.

[image: Flat Curve Segments]

---

If you uncheck `Radius` in the curve settings, you can model a section of the street easily in the same size that you want it to be when it's applied to the curve.

[image: Curve Settings]

---

In order to stop the single section from overlapping with the curve, I set the objects' origins to the 3D cursor, which I snapped to the center before.
It was the easiest part to model the street section at a 1:1 scale with the correct axes.

[image: Road Section Wireframe]

Just make sure to add a few loop cuts to have it bend smoothly.

Have a nice day.

Comment: When I export to .fbx having done Mzidare's reply I get this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/plOju.png
Do you think maybe doing it by your way this error could disappear? 
Your way seems more ordered.
Thanks for your time :) @Cebbi

Comment: I didn't try to export it yet, and I can't try it within the next 5 hours. I can't imagine any reason, why my way should export easier. Try to apply some modifiers before exporting.